# determine address of underlying s3 bucket in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I can run this query in Athena frontend:

```
SELECT * FROM analysisdata."iris" limit 10;
```

when I click on table properties I get this for location:

```
s3://Bladata887342ac-a3ce-4600-94d0-9092f4a6bd20/Iris
```

Is this what I have to use as s3_staging_dir in Python code like so:

```
cursor = connect(aws_access_key_id='xyz',
                 aws_secret_access_key='xyz',
                 s3_staging_dir='s3://Bladata887342ac-a3ce-4600-94d0-9092f4a6bd20/Iris',
                 region_name='us-east-1').cursor()
```

Also the S3 bucket is hosted in:

```
EU (Ireland)
```

what would be the region_name?

Comment: I am not sure if the region_name of the cursor is related to the S3 bucket region. I believe it is the one you're in when you created your analysisdata in Athena frontEnd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ireland should be `eu-west-1`.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region